# Sum product across multiple ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following two use cases:

**Column A** - A longer series of dates. Date may be repeated.

**Column B** - A short series of dates, dates are unique but not necessarily sequential in value.

**Column C** - A longer series of values associated with the longer series of dates.

My goal is to say - for each value in column B, find all the values in column A, set to true or 1 and then select the value in column C associated with the specific value in column A, sum across all values.

```
= SUMPRODUCT((B1:Bn=A1:Am)*(C1:Cm))
```

n < m

I have also just tried to count instances using

```
= SUMPRODUCT((B1:Bn=A1:Am)*(1))
```

I have tried both as arrays as well and in each case, I'm getting N/A.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap a SUMIF() in SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,B1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)),C:C))
```

Since SUMPRODUCT is an array type formula we need to limit the range in Column B as it will iterate through each cell in that reference.

The `B1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))` will return a range that starts in B1 and goes to the last cell with a number in it in Column B, Thus limiting the iterations to only those that have a value.

[image]